# PNG overlay Script (Google Drive)

Tags: google-apps-script

I need the ability to add a .PNG file watermark to any JPG image that is added to a google drive folder and save the result in a new google drive folder.

Can anyone recommend a script or program that accomplishes this?

Note: The PNG overlay image would be saved in a google drive folder.  I tried Wappwolf "stamp a logo" but can't seem to make it work properly.  I would prefer an automated script if this can be done.

Also: To keep it simple I would make the PNG watermark the same size as the JPG image

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to directly modify image content with Apps Script. Your best bet is to use a third party tool.